# How to use partial IP address in /etc/sysconfig/iptables for the "-s" flag?

Tags: linux, centos, security, iptables, ip

in this example it is a full ip

ip is: 1.1.1.1

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```

but suppose i want to allow any ip that simply starts with:

1.1.

because for example my internet ip always starts with 1.1. but rest changes time to time.

i want to be able to do something like this:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -s 1.1.* -j ACCEPT
```

i do not think this will work because i think in world of computers they use ranges and etc rather than the wild card symbols.

Range stuff looks very complex to me. is there something like this with a wild card style concept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the ip address `1.1.*`, you would use `1.1.0.0/16`.   This notation is used for [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) (classless inter-domain routing) and is the standard method used to specify blocks of addresses.  The `/16` indicates the network includes all of the lower 16 bits of the address, so it matches in this case the address block from `1.1.0.0` to `1.1.255.255`.